# Shader program to Vertex + Fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am studying [a tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial37/tutorial37.html) which uses this shader:

```
struct VSInput
{
  vec3 Position;
  vec2 TexCoord;
  vec3 Normal;  
};

interface VSOutput
{
  vec3 WorldPos;
  vec2 TexCoord;
  vec3 Normal;  
};


uniform mat4 gWVP;
uniform mat4 gWorld;

shader VSmain(in VSInput VSin:0, out VSOutput VSout)         
{                   
  gl_Position = gWVP * vec4(VSin.Position, 1.0);
  VSout.TexCoord   = VSin.TexCoord;                  
  VSout.Normal     = (gWorld * vec4(VSin.Normal, 0.0)).xyz;   
  VSout.WorldPos   = (gWorld * vec4(VSin.Position, 1.0)).xyz; 
};


struct FSOutput
{                   
  vec3 WorldPos;    
  vec3 Diffuse;     
  vec3 Normal;      
  vec3 TexCoord;    
};


uniform sampler2D gColorMap;                

shader FSmain(in VSOutput FSin, out FSOutput FSout)                                 
{                                           
FSout.WorldPos = FSin.WorldPos;                 
FSout.Diffuse  = texture(gColorMap, FSin.TexCoord).xyz; 
FSout.Normal   = normalize(FSin.Normal);                    
FSout.TexCoord = vec3(FSin.TexCoord, 0.0);              
};

program GeometryPass
{
  vs(410)=VSmain();
  fs(410)=FSmain();
};
```

It's a geometry pass shader for deferred rendering.
I am now trying to port it into a QT based program but my code can only load vertex and fragment shaders separately.

Can someone give a suggestion of how I can split the above into 2 loadable shaders ?

Also, as far as I understand, this shader needs OpenGL core 4.1.0. Is this really necessary or is there some other way to achieve the same result using a lower level (let's say 3.3) ?

Comment: That isn't valid GLSL.  It's close, but it has some funny extra stuff which must be related to the particular environment it was written for.

Comment: It's loaded with [glfx](https://code.google.com/p/glfx/) and I don't want to drag it in my code. There has to be a way though to go back to a valid and clean GLSL code. I just don't know how :( Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a CgFX variant using GLSL code with a bunch of Cg syntax added.  To convert it to valid GLSL, you need to split it into separate vertex and fragment shaders, rename the entry points for each to be `main` and move the arguments to the entry point out to be multiple global variables rather than structs (renaming things to avoid collisions.)  The most subtle detail is the `:0` semantic on the VSmain input argument, which becomes `layout` qualifiers on the corresponding `in` globals.

So the vertex shader becomes:

```
#version 410 compatibility
//struct VSInput
//{
  in layout(location = 0) vec3 Position;
  in layout(location = 1) vec2 in_TexCoord;
  in layout(location = 2) vec3 in_Normal;  
//};

//interface VSOutput
//{
  out vec3 WorldPos;
  out vec2 TexCoord;
  out vec3 Normal;  
//};


uniform mat4 gWVP;
uniform mat4 gWorld;

//shader VSmain(in VSInput VSin:0, out VSOutput VSout)
main()     
{                   
  gl_Position = gWVP * vec4(Position, 1.0);
  TexCoord    = in_TexCoord;                  
  Normal      = (gWorld * vec4(in_Normal, 0.0)).xyz;   
  WorldPos    = (gWorld * vec4(Position, 1.0)).xyz; 
}
```

The fragment shader is similarly transformed